# How to query table Using Group By, Limit and Sum in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, sum

| A_id | B_id | L | M | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 7 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 8 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 9 | 4 | 4 | 2 |

Suppose P = 2, Q = 3. I would like to find the A_id such that the following are satisfied:

- the sum of the P greatest L records for A_id >= P+Q
- the sum of the P greatest M records for A_id >= P
- the sum of the P greatest N records for A_id >= Q

I have attempted to solve this and see I will need to use a combination of GROUP BY, ORDER BY, LIMIT and SUM but there is so much going on that I am just lost in how to implement this in SQL. It is beyond my current capability.

Please could someone explain to me how to write a query like this for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this

```
SELECT A_id
FROM (
    SELECT 
        A_id,
        SUM(L) AS sum_L,
        SUM(M) AS sum_M,
        SUM(N) AS sum_N
    FROM your_table_name
    GROUP BY A_id
) AS sums
ORDER BY 
    (SELECT SUM(L) FROM (SELECT L FROM your_table_name WHERE A_id = sums.A_id ORDER BY L DESC LIMIT 2) AS P_greatest_L) DESC,
    (SELECT SUM(M) FROM (SELECT M FROM your_table_name WHERE A_id = sums.A_id ORDER BY M DESC LIMIT 2) AS P_greatest_M) DESC,
    (SELECT SUM(N) FROM (SELECT N FROM your_table_name WHERE A_id = sums.A_id ORDER BY N DESC LIMIT 3) AS P_greatest_N) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Appreciate the response but by using LIMIT 1 does that not mean you can only get at most one A_id ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL ≥ 8, you could use a CTE to add row numbering and then conditional aggregation based on the row numbering:

```
SET @P = 2, @Q = 3;

WITH greatest AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A_id ORDER BY L DESC) AS greatest_l,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A_id ORDER BY M DESC) AS greatest_m,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A_id ORDER BY N DESC) AS greatest_n
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT A_id
FROM greatest
GROUP BY A_id
HAVING SUM(IF(greatest_l <= @P, L, 0)) >= @P + @Q
   AND SUM(IF(greatest_m <= @P, M, 0)) >= @P
   AND SUM(IF(greatest_n <= @P, N, 0)) >= @Q;
```

Based on your sample data the output is:

| A_id |
| --- |
| 1 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NRRadEQt).